# Some special effect for Moderators

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderators

Is there any special effect (Some green indication or something like that) can provide to SO Moderators ?

[image]

If yes , other users can easily notice the Moderators , how they are active in SO etc.

Comment: Why down-vote ? Please explain.

Comment: You don't say why you want this and you don't say what's wrong with the diamond which you can see in the screenshot already.

Comment: I'm upvoting this. With all the nonsense unicode I've seen in people's usernames, I don't think the fact that the ♦ is a special case is abundantly obvious.

Comment: I suggest exploding cigars.

Comment: @yannis you was trollin' rite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators have a "special effect". It's the diamond: ♦

That diamond means they are a moderator. Normal users can't have it. You can only get it by becoming a moderator.